# Vue component over-complication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a date range selector, and while this works, I feel like I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be. Is there a more elegant way of writing this?

Possibly using computed values or watches?

```js
<template>
 <form>
  <select  @change="rangeSelection">          
             <option 
                 v-for="(option, key) in rangeOptions"
                 :key="key"
                 :value="key">
                 {{option.display}}
             </option>
     </select>
        </form>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'DateRangeChooser',
  data: () => {
    return {
     selectedRange: "last7Days",
  startDate: moment().subtract(8, 'days'),
  endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
     rangeOptions: {
      last7Days: {
       display: 'Last 7 Days',
       startDate: moment().subtract(8, 'days'),
       endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
      },
      lastWeek: {
       display: 'Last Week',
       startDate: moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'week'),
       endDate: moment().endOf('week').subtract(1, 'week')
      },
      last30days: {
       display: 'Last 30 days',
       startDate: moment().subtract(31, 'days'),
       endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
      }
     }
    }
  },  
  methods: {
   rangeSelection: function(e){
    this.endDate = this.rangeOptions[e.currentTarget.value].endDate;
    this.startDate = this.rangeOptions[e.currentTarget.value].startDate;
   }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: this.selectedRange.enddate

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One of the problems of asking for a more elegant way to write something is that it really differs for every person, some people are fine with it, others really dislike the moment part, and then you also have other people who want more watchers or computed properties. The best way to have this code review is asking other co-workers/friends, as they are the ones most likely to interact with the code in the future, out of everyone.